# There is no cycles render option in my blender (v 2.79.1)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

As shown in the pictures, my cycles render addon is enabled, but there is no `cycles render` option in my pull down tab!

[image: Screenshot dropdown]

[image: Screenshot addon settings]

Comment: Is it still enabled when you restart blender?

Comment: yes its still enabled when i restart

Comment: Hmm... weird. I've never seen this before. You could report the bug to the Blender.org website.

Comment: Are you perchance running a dev build (buildbot/self-compiled/graphicall) from the last few days? There was an API tweak that briefly broke the Cycles addon. It's been fixed now, no need to report it again.

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.79.1 has not been officially released so this problem has probably arisen as it is a dev/beta build, you can simply report this to blender as a bug (the purpose of these builds) and either revert to an official blender release or just stick it out. Happy Blending! :)

Comment: Already fixed, no need to report it again.